# Collect Waterfall Data

Tags: javascript, performance, networking

I noticed in Chrome, I can view the waterfall metrics of individual elements. Particularly, I'm interested in the image load. Is there any way for Javascript to be able to collect this data, since it is browser-based? I know I can collect the DOM load with performance.timing but that doesn't give me any image load metrics.

I know I can also create a start/stop timer for the image itself, but that won't give me details about the breakdown of the load.

Ideally, the solution should be able to work for all browsers, not just Chrome. Any ideas?

[image: Waterfall Metrics]